# retrieve image using curl - php (issue)

Tags: php, curl

I need to retrieve image from database and store it to a folder. Once I used copy function with direct URL file-access to get the image from database..But it didn't work in our server. because **allow_url_fopen** is off in our server.. So now I am trying curl function to get the image..

This is my code

```
  $curl = curl_init("http://localhost/matrimony/admin/getImage.php?id=24");
  curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  if(($data = curl_exec($curl)) === false)
        echo "curl error";
  else{
    $im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
    if ($im !== false) {
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        imagejpeg($im);
        imagedestroy($im);
    }
    else {
        echo 'An error occurred.';
    }
    //return $data;
  }
  curl_close ($curl);
```

The result is

```
ÿØÿàJFIFÿþ>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), default quality ÿÛC    $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342ÿÛC  2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222ÿÀXµ"ÿÄ ÿÄµ}!1AQa"q2‘¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br‚ %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚáâãäåæçèéêñòóôõö÷øùúÿÄ ÿÄµw!1AQaq"2B‘¡±Á #3RðbrÑ $4á%ñ&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚâãäåæçèéêòóôõö÷øùúÿÚ?…Z¬+UUj™Z€-+TŠÕ]Z¤V ¨ÝQ«S•¨Û¨ÝMf¢€ Õ½£émÛ©×kmýÚ·ðÿ´Õ6›£­º­ÅÜj× þ­~òÇÿÙU‹Ûæó>ÏÍ'ñ7÷hK™$™¾Ëlß¼eûßÝ_þ
```

and my **getImage** code is

```
    $image = $_GET['id'];
    $rs = mysql_query("select ImgData from tblphotos where PhotoId=$image");
$n=mysql_num_rows($rs);
if($n>0)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs);
    $imagebytes = $row['ImgData'];
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    print $imagebytes;
}
```

Is there any mistakes in my code?. I don't know what I have to do..

Comment: add curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.imagejpeg.php   second parameter if you want to save it to a file

Comment: @ Haim Evgi i tried this.. but nothing is changed..again i got the same result.. :(

Comment: @Daniel Ruf:  Thank u so much.. i hv been trying this for nearly 3 hours.. now i got it.. ur solution works perfectly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php.net/manual/de/function.imagejpeg.php second parameter if you want to save it to a file (should be an answer and not a comment